# How to send event to multiple forms in Delphi

Tags: forms, delphi

In my application I have multiple forms that can be visible at the same time and they all show disk space (files, hard disk size etc.) in the same size units. So all of them show disk space in Bytes, KB, MB, GB or TB. I also have a seperate settings form in which the user can change the display size, he wants in the other forms. Once the user clicks OK in the settings form, I want all the other (open) forms to immediately change their size settings.

Every form has a protected procedure SetViewSettings, which takes care of the job. They are all descendants of an ancestor form which defines SetViewSettings as virtual and abstract. The actual displayed forms override the SetViewSettings method of the ancestor. So far no problems.

Because I don't want to call every individual form (FormX.SetViewSetttings, FormY.SetViewSettings, etc.), I am using the following solution:

```
procedure TApplicationForms.SetUnits;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    if Screen.Forms[I] is TfrAncestorInfo then
      with Screen.Forms[I] as TfrAncestorInfo do
        acSetUnits.Execute;
end;
```

This procedure is called from the SettingsForm as the user clicks OK.
TFrAncestorInfo is a descendant of TForm, declaring the SetViewSettings method as virtual and abstract. acSetUnits is an Action, declared in TfrAncestorInfo, which only calls SetViewSettings. This all works fine, but the risk lies in creating a new descendant form of TFrAncestorInfo, whilest forgetting to override the SetViewSettings method, in which case you will run into an 'Abstract Error' exception.

Are there any alternatives to calling the SetViewSettings method in the forms, without listing (calling) all the descendant forms individually? I know of messages and events, but I don't know how to use these in a multiple forms situation. In general: how can I directly send a message to or generate an event for all TFrAncestorInfo descendant forms, without listing them individually?

Comment: A simpler solution would be to ditch the `acSetUnits.Execute`, and make `SetViewUnits` non-abstract, but either empty or with minimal shared code, e.g. `FViewUnits := Value`. Also ditch the `acSetUnits.Execute`, and call `SetViewUnits(newUnits)` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option (there are many other possible options) would be to send a custom message to every Form.  No need for worry about virtual/abstract overriding, type checking, etc.  Only the Forms that implement a message handler will react to the message, the rest will simply ignore it.

```
const
  WM_SETTINGS_UPDATED = WM_APP + 1;

procedure TApplicationForms.SetUnits;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    Screen.Forms[I].Perform(WM_SETTINGS_UPDATED, 0, 0);
end;
```

```
type
  TSomeForm = class(TBaseForm)
  private
    procedure WMSettingsUpdated(var Message: TMessage); message WM_SETTINGS_UPDATED;
  protected
    procedure SetViewSettings;
  end;

procedure TSomeForm.WMSettingsUpdated(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  SetViewSettings;
end;

procedure TSomeForm.SetViewSettings;
begin
  //...
end;
```

Comment: This does exactly, what I was looking for. The solution also eliminates the TAction, as @Gerry was suggesting.

Comment: You can use a `TAction` broadcast as well. This is how the `TStatusBar.AutoHint` feature works, for instance. When the `TApplication.Hint` property is set (such as from a menu item) and `TApplication.OnHint` is not assigned, `TApplication` executes a `THintAction` that is broadcast throughout the entire app. `TStatusBar` reacts to that broadcast by overriding the virtual `TComponent.ExecuteAction()` method. So any `TStatusBar` on any Form can display the same `Hint` value. You could broadcast a custom `TAction` that all of your interested Forms can react to.

Comment: [`System.Messaging`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging) is another option which will work on all platforms and is not limited on forms